# Structure of a transaction receipt

Tags: transactions, contract-development, receipts

What does it mean line by line?

```
   Result: {
    "blockHash": "0xe6b110c9167d9aabeb13b02a7b9358d879426474a79170403d67da33a391dbdc",
      "blockNumber": 665,
      "contractAddress": null,
      "cumulativeGasUsed": 68527,
      "from": "0x0fd8cd36bebcee2bcb35e24c925af5cf7ea9475d",
      "gasUsed": 68527,
      "logs": [
        {
          "address": "0x91067b439e1be22196a5f64ee61e803670ba5be9",
          "blockHash": "0xe6b110c9167d9aabeb13b02a7b9358d879426474a79170403d67da33a391dbdc",
          "blockNumber": 665,
          "data": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000576eca940000000000000000000000000fd8cd36bebcee2bcb35e24c925af5cf7ea9475d0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
          "logIndex": 0,
          "topics": [
            "0x72d0d212148041614162a44c61fef731170dd7cccc35d1974690989386be0999"
          ],
          "transactionHash": "0xad62c939b2e865f13c61eebcb221d2c9737955e506b69fb624210d3fd4e0035b",
          "transactionIndex": 0
        }
      ],
      "root": "7583254379574ee8eb2943c3ee41582a0041156215e2c7d82e363098c89fe21b",
      "to": "0x91067b439e1be22196a5f64ee61e803670ba5be9",
      "transactionHash": "0xad62c939b2e865f13c61eebcb221d2c9737955e506b69fb624210d3fd4e0035b",
      "transactionIndex": 0
    }
    Transaction cost: 68527 gas.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt

```
Returns

Object - A transaction receipt object, or null when no receipt was found:

blockHash: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the block where this transaction was in.
blockNumber: Number - block number where this transaction was in.
transactionHash: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the transaction.
transactionIndex: Number - integer of the transactions index position in the block.
from: String, 20 Bytes - address of the sender.
to: String, 20 Bytes - address of the receiver. null when its a contract creation transaction.
cumulativeGasUsed: Number - The total amount of gas used when this transaction was executed in the block.
gasUsed: Number - The amount of gas used by this specific transaction alone.
contractAddress: String - 20 Bytes - The contract address created, if the transaction was a contract creation, otherwise null.
logs: Array - Array of log objects, which this transaction generated.
status : String - '0x0' indicates transaction failure , '0x1' indicates transaction succeeded.
```

Here are some other details for properties that aren't as clear:

`cumulativeGasUsed` see
[What is and how to calculate 'cumulative gas used'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/what-is-and-how-to-calculate-cumulative-gas-used)

For using `logs`, see 
[How do I parse the transaction receipt log with web3.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/how-do-i-parse-the-transaction-receipt-log-with-web3-js)

The [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) doesn't mention anything about `root`, but `root` is the hash of the root of the *intermediate* state trie after this specific transaction has been applied, see [What is the 'root' of a transaction receipt?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6537/what-is-the-root-of-a-transaction-receipt)