# What is the 'root' of a transaction receipt?

Tags: transactions, receipts

[web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) returns an object with a `root` property and is currently undocumented in the [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt).

```
Result: {
    ...
      "root": "7583254379574ee8eb2943c3ee41582a0041156215e2c7d82e363098c89fe21b",
      "to": "0x91067b439e1be22196a5f64ee61e803670ba5be9",
      "transactionHash": "0xad62c939b2e865f13c61eebcb221d2c9737955e506b69fb624210d3fd4e0035b",
      "transactionIndex": 0
    }
```

1. What is this `root`?  It is not the same as the `receiptRoot` from `web3.eth.getBlock`.
2. What is the relationship between these roots?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the hash of the root of the state trie, whereas `receiptRoot` is the hash of the array of receipts for a given block.

---

### root

In [`GetTransactionReceipt()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/667a386d87de64587061c2462773977e8a9dc98a/eth/api.go#L1091) in `api.go` there's set of mappings, one of which is:

```
"root":              common.Bytes2Hex(receipt.PostState),
```

Looking at [`receipt.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/receipt.go), `PostState` is a `byte` array:

```
// Receipt represents the results of a transaction.
type Receipt struct {
    // Consensus fields
    PostState         []byte
    CumulativeGasUsed *big.Int
    Bloom             Bloom
    Logs              vm.Logs
```

This is set in [`NewReceipt()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/receipt.go#L44) to a value passed in from [`state_processor.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/state_processor.go#L160):

```
receipt := types.NewReceipt(statedb.IntermediateRoot().Bytes(), usedGas)
```

...and `IntermediateRoot()` is defined in [`statedb.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/state/statedb.go#L362) as:

```
// IntermediateRoot computes the current root hash of the state trie.
// It is called in between transactions to get the root hash that
// goes into transaction receipts.
```

---

### receiptRoot

In [`block.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/block.go#L188):

```
// The values of TxHash, UncleHash, ReceiptHash and Bloom in header
// are ignored and set to values derived from the given txs, uncles
// and receipts.
```

With the pertinent code in that function being:

```
b.header.ReceiptHash = DeriveSha(Receipts(receipts))
```

And in [`api.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/667a386d87de64587061c2462773977e8a9dc98a/eth/api.go#L824):

```
"receiptRoot":      b.ReceiptHash(),
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the hash of the root of the *intermediate* state trie after the particular transaction has been applied.